# Can I dynamically change the Clip property with JS?

Tags: javascript, css

i've been trying to change the clip property with JS using input value and range input values. The idea of the exercise is as follow:

1. I can specify how much space the yellow circle will take up in the input field,
2. I can animate the circle.

Here's my current setup

```
HTML: 
    </div>
        <div class="layer-one">
        <div class="layer-three"></div>
        <div class="layer-two"></div>
    </div>



       .layer-one {
      margin-top: 4em;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: lightgray;
        margin-right: 4em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .layer-two {
        width: 200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color: #ffdb4d;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 0px); 
        transform: rotate(20deg);
    }

    .layer-three {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 10px;  
        z-index: 10000;
    } 

And here are the functions: 

    const valueInput = document.querySelector("#valueInput");
    const layerTwo = document.querySelector(".layer-two");
    const rangeInput = document.querySelector("#rangeInput");

    rangeInput.addEventListener("input", ()=> {
    let rangeValue = rangeInput.value;
    layerTwo.style.clip = "rect(0" + rangeValue + "px" + rangeValue + "px" + "0)";

    valueInput.addEventListener("input", ()=> {
    let valueFromInput = valueInput.value;
    layerTwo.style.clip = "rect(0" + valueFromInput + "px" + valueFromInput + "px" + "0)";
})
```

The problem i'm trying to solve is changing second and third value of the clip property with the inputs. Thus, I will be able to dynamically change the amount of space the yellow circle takes up.

[Screen of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLJW0.png)

Comment: Why not just add a on click event to the value input, and call this line again `layerTwo.style.clip = "rect(0" + valueFromInput + "px" + valueFromInput + "px" + "0)";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing arguments separators for rect:

If for example `rangeValue=100`, `"rect(0" + rangeValue + "px" + rangeValue + "px" + "0)"` evaluates to `"rect(0100px100px0)"`

it must be something like: `"rect(0," + rangeValue + "px," + rangeValue + "px," + "0)"`